# Fast format option for HDs recommended in dedicated servers?

Tags: hard-drive, dedicated-server, formatting

I'm learning about dedicated servers and have a very simple question.

In windows server 2008, is it a good practice to fast format your HDs for the first time? Or should i perform a slow one?

Which are the differences mainly?

I've got 2 MBR and one GPT disks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered by this answer:

https://serverfault.com/a/10803/87408

> Basically, quick format doesn't do a scan of the disk to check for bad sectors.
>
> Here's a MS Article[1] on the topic.
>
> [1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly the main diffrence is as follows

a quick format, removes the MFT (Master file table) on NTFS partions, so basicly removes the information telling the disc where the data is stored.

a full format *should* write zeros to every sector.

I would imagine that discs from the factory (or new) should be pretty blank, so a quick format should suffice.